# How to "force" tensorflow to use a specific version of CUDA?

Tags: tensorflow

Each time I run my code I get this error:

```
Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.10.0';
```

But I don't want to use this  version of cuda (10). I want to use cuda 12.

I have tried to do :

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-12
```

Where `/usr/local/cuda-12` is the path where cuda12 is installed.

But this does not change anything.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot use the version you want, you could try building tensorflow from source against CUDA 12, but it is likely that the answer is a plain no.

Comment: do you mean that the CUDA version is determined exclusively by the tensorflow version ? (I am using TF1.15)

Comment: Yes that is even mentioned in the TF website.